# How to write OS X Finder Comments from python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a python script that creates numerous images files based on a variety of inputs in OS X Yosemite. I am trying to write the inputs used to create each file as 'Finder comments' as each file is created so that IF the the output is visually interesting I can look at the specific input values that generated the file.  I've verified that this can be done easily with apple script.

`tell application "Finder" to set comment of (POSIX file "/Users/mgarito/Desktop/Random_Pixel_Color/2015-01-03_14.04.21.png" as alias) to {Val1, Val2, Val3} as Unicode text`

Afterward, upon selecting the file and showing its info (cmd+i) the Finder comments clearly display the expected text 'Val1, Val2, Val2'.

This is further confirmed by running mdls [File/Path/Name] before and after the applescript is used which clearly shows the expected text has been properly added.

The problem is I can't figure out how to incorporate this into my python script to save myself.

Im under the impression the solution should* be something to the effect of:
`VarList = [Var1, Var2, Var3]
Fiele = [File/Path/Name]
file.os.system.add(kMDItemFinderComment, VarList)`

As a side note I've also look at xattr -w [Attribute_Name] [Attribute_Value] [File/Path/Name] but found that though this will store the attribute, it is not stored in the desired location. Instead it ends up in an affiliated pList which is not what I'm after.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my way to do that.

First you need to install [`applescript`](https://pypi.org/project/applescript/) package using `pip install applescript` command.

Here is a function to add comments to a file:

```
def set_comment(file_path, comment_text):
    import applescript
    applescript.tell.app("Finder", f'set comment of (POSIX file "{file_path}" as alias) to "{comment_text}" as Unicode text')
```

and then I'm just using it like this:

```
set_comment('/Users/UserAccountName/Pictures/IMG_6860.MOV', 'my comment')
```

Answer (score 1):

After more digging, I was able to locate a python applescript bundle: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-applescript

This got me to a workable answer, though I'd still prefer to do this natively in python if anyone has a better option?

---

```
import applescript

NewFile = '[File/Path/Name]' <br>
Comment = "Almost there.."

AddComment = applescript.AppleScript('''

    on run {arg1, arg2}
       tell application "Finder" to set comment of (POSIX file arg1 as alias) to arg2 as Unicode text
       return
    end run

''')

print(AddComment.run(NewFile, Comment))

print("Done")
```

Comment: It's better than what I was doing, namely using `commands` to run `osascript`!

Comment: This works. You must install pyobjc first (with pip3) and install applescript manually. Don’t include the brackets in your file path.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function to get comment of a file.

```
def get_comment(file_path):
    import applescript
    return applescript.tell.app("Finder", f'get comment of (POSIX file "{file_path}" as alias)').out
print(get_comment('Your Path'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net), a high-level Apple event bridge that is sadly no longer officially supported but still works (and saw an [updated release in Jan. 2021](https://pypi.org/project/appscript/)). Here is an example of reading and setting the comment on a file:

```py
import appscript
import mactypes

# Get a handle on the Finder.
finder = appscript.app('Finder')

# Tell Finder to select the file.
file = finder.items[mactypes.Alias("/path/to/a/file")]

# Print the current comment
comment = file.comment()
print("Current comment: " + comment)

# Set a new comment.
file.comment.set("New comment")

# Print the current comment again to verify.
comment = file.comment()
print("Current comment: " + comment)
```

Despite that the author of appscript recommends against using it in new projects, I used it recently to create a command-line utility called [Urial](https://github.com/mhucka/urial) for the specialized purpose of writing and updating URIs in Finder comments. Perhaps its code can serve as  an an additional example of using appscript to manipulate Finder comments.